# Vue2: Moment JS countdown timer

Tags: methods, vuejs2, countdown, requestanimationframe

I have a problem which I don't know how to solve.

I have a component with an end-date, and I want to show a countdown timer with the remaining seconds.

I use moment JS for this, but I don't know how to implement this in Vue2.

Should I use a computed method?

```
        computed: {
            timer: function() {
                var now = moment();
                var then = moment().add(180, 'seconds');
                return moment().to(then);
                (function timerLoop() {
                    this.timer = countdown(then).toString();
                    requestAnimationFrame(timerLoop);
                })();
            },
```

Problem is that I have to return the value before vue2 shows it. But I also have to use requestAnimationFrame to update this every second.

Can anyone help me out? And what is the best way to use this? setInterval or requestAnimationFrame? I think the latter, because there will be 100+ timers on 1 page, so performance is necessary.

So long story, short:
[Momentjs and countdown timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463376/momentjs-and-countdown-timer)

How can I create an Vue2 function/method/mixin of this? And which updates every second?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a time-loop for each timer, I suggest having a single interval updating a value on the model every second and using Vue's reactivity to trigger updates to the computed properties.

[I've created a pen where you easily can play around with number active timers to see how it impacts performance.](https://codepen.io/kristofferostlund/pen/mmrxWq)

```
    data() {
        return {
            interval: null,
            now: new Date(),
            dates: [], // Your dates here
        }
    },
    computed() {
        timers() {
            return this.dates.map(then => moment(this.now).to(then))
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.now = new Date()
        }, 1000)
    }
```